# loading icon(svg) in explorer doesn't work.

Tags: svg

I using a loading-icon in my site. This works good in Chrome and etc, but it doesn't work normally in explorer. 
My Explorer version is 11.0. I searched that explorer support svg file after 9 version. So I don't know why.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> loading icon test
</head>
<body>
<div style="background:gray;">

<svg class="lds-spinner" width="200px"  height="200px"  
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 100 100" 
preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" style="background: none;"><g 
transform="rotate(0 50 50)">
      <rect x="47" y="24" rx="9.4" ry="4.8" width="6" height="12" fill="#ffffff">
        <animate attributeName="opacity" values="1;0" times="0;1" dur="1s" begin="-0.9166666666666666s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
      </rect>
    </g><g transform="rotate(30 50 50)">
      <rect x="47" y="24" rx="9.4" ry="4.8" width="6" height="12" fill="#ffffff">
        <animate attributeName="opacity" values="1;0" times="0;1" dur="1s" begin="-0.8333333333333334s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
      </rect>
    </g><g transform="rotate(60 50 50)">
      <rect x="47" y="24" rx="9.4" ry="4.8" width="6" height="12" fill="#ffffff">
        <animate attributeName="opacity" values="1;0" times="0;1" dur="1s" begin="-0.75s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
      </rect>
     </g><g transform="rotate(90 50 50)">
      <rect x="47" y="24" rx="9.4" ry="4.8" width="6" height="12" fill="#ffffff">
        <animate attributeName="opacity" values="1;0" times="0;1" dur="1s" begin="-0.6666666666666666s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
      </rect>
     </g><g transform="rotate(120 50 50)">
      <rect x="47" y="24" rx="9.4" ry="4.8" width="6" height="12" fill="#ffffff">
        <animate attributeName="opacity" values="1;0" times="0;1" dur="1s" begin="-0.5833333333333334s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
      </rect>
    </g><g transform="rotate(150 50 50)">
      <rect x="47" y="24" rx="9.4" ry="4.8" width="6" height="12" fill="#ffffff">
        <animate attributeName="opacity" values="1;0" times="0;1" dur="1s" begin="-0.5s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
     </rect>
    </g><g transform="rotate(180 50 50)">
      <rect x="47" y="24" rx="9.4" ry="4.8" width="6" height="12" fill="#ffffff">
        <animate attributeName="opacity" values="1;0" times="0;1" dur="1s" begin="-0.4166666666666667s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
      </rect>
    </g><g transform="rotate(210 50 50)">
      <rect x="47" y="24" rx="9.4" ry="4.8" width="6" height="12" fill="#ffffff">
        <animate attributeName="opacity" values="1;0" times="0;1" dur="1s" begin="-0.3333333333333333s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
      </rect>
    </g><g transform="rotate(240 50 50)">
      <rect x="47" y="24" rx="9.4" ry="4.8" width="6" height="12" fill="#ffffff">
        <animate attributeName="opacity" values="1;0" times="0;1" dur="1s" begin="-0.25s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
       </rect>
     </g><g transform="rotate(270 50 50)">
       <rect x="47" y="24" rx="9.4" ry="4.8" width="6" height="12" fill="#ffffff">
        <animate attributeName="opacity" values="1;0" times="0;1" dur="1s" begin="-0.16666666666666666s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
      </rect>
    </g><g transform="rotate(300 50 50)">
      <rect x="47" y="24" rx="9.4" ry="4.8" width="6" height="12" fill="#ffffff">
         <animate attributeName="opacity" values="1;0" times="0;1" dur="1s" begin="-0.08333333333333333s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
      </rect>
     </g><g transform="rotate(330 50 50)">
      <rect x="47" y="24" rx="9.4" ry="4.8" width="6" height="12" fill="#ffffff">
        <animate attributeName="opacity" values="1;0" times="0;1" dur="1s" begin="0s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
      </rect>
    </g></svg>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't know if that kind of animation works on IE. May be change it to this: https://jsfiddle.net/z8w4vuau/50/

Comment: IE doesn't support SMIL natively, however the [fakesmile](https://leunen.me/fakesmile/) library can provide support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internet Explorer and Edge don't support SMIL animations ( tag) as you can see on this page:
https://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-smil

You could use CSS animations or as @robert-longson said [fakesmile](https://leunen.me/fakesmile/) if you want to keep your existing code.